# "Contact" collective link does not appear on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, collectives

There is a link in the `google-cloud` collective labeled "contact":

[image]

This link is visible with the rest of the external links, as long as the width of the screen is >817px.

For any width resolution lower than 817px, the link disappears and is not shown with the rest of external links in the drop-down:

[image]

This UI behaviour also happens in the `go` collective.

Comment: Bug persists at 960 pixels wide (half of a FHD screen). The links snap in at right around 1000 pixels of width.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for logging this bug, the developers have been made aware and will look into it.

Comment: This bug has been fixed. External contact link now appears ~963px width.