# How can I contact a collective?

Tags: support, status-completed, collectives

I've joined a couple of Collectives.

There doesn't appear to be a way to interact with a Collective's administrators.

In one Collective, I'm a frequent contributor, but it's unclear to me how contributors are becoming "Recognized Members".

The Collective doesn't (appear) to describe what contributes to becoming recognized nor do I have a way to ask the Collective for this information.

Comment: [There's a "Contact" button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409142) that probably does what you want.

Comment: When the Go collective launched, there was a blog post (on the Go official blog). This post provided an email address IIRC on the stackoverflow domain. The post also stated people could use that address for inquiries related to the collective. I actually sent an email asking what was the process to become Recognized Member, if any. I never got any reply. My personal reckoning is that Recognized Member status is on invite or based in being “recognized” in the English sense of the term outside SO.

Comment: This: https://go.dev/blog/stackoverflow —  *If you are interested in becoming a Recognized Member, please email stackoverflow@golang.org.*

Comment: Thank you both (@cigien, @blackgreen). I was trying not to name names but it is the Google Collective that I wanted to engage; I feel not yet worthy of consideration for the Go Collective.

Comment: Aha... So I'd tried the "contact" button on the Google Cloud Collective previously. I don't use Twitter or Insta. The contact button takes me to a Slack login prompt that appears to only accept @google.com or Apple (!?) users. So I'm outta luck.

Comment: @DazWilkin We are currently looking into this for you. Will update when we get a solution. Appreciate the patience :)

Comment: I appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: @Piper "\@DazWilkin We are currently looking into this for you. Will update when we get a solution. Appreciate the patience :)" Any progress?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks again for patience!

For the time being we would like to ask you to send us a message using the support page (link: https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and add which Collective you would like to become Recognized Member of and the user account that you're using. We will forward this information to the Collective owners.

We'll be adding a category 'Collectives' on that form. To make sure it gets directed to the right people.

On the slightly longer term we'll be working on an in-product solution for these types of requests.

Comment: thank you for your diligence and responsiveness. I decided to leave the Google Cloud Platform collective. There was no benefit to me in being a member. The lack of transparency on recognized membership left me with some distaste. The collective also includes a catch-all set of tags which required me to apply filters to exclude content to try to focus on my areas of interest.