# Collections: A New Feature for Collectives on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, collectives, announcement, collections

Today we are launching ["Collections"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collections-overview), a new feature in Collectives, designed to help collective Members easily discover and collaboratively build upon high-quality content about a specific subject area. Take a look at the new collections in the [R Language](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language?tab=collections), [CI/CD](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/ci-cd?tab=collections), [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php?tab=collections), and [NLP](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp?tab=collections) collectives.

### What’s the feature, and how will it work?

Collections enables users to group existing questions, answers, and articles together based on a particular theme or for a particular purpose. In many ways, it is similar to [the feature of the same name that exists on Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/06/introducing-collections-on-stack-overflow-for-teams/), but there are differences, as well as some additional functionality.

For this first experimental iteration, collective Admins will create each collection, and work with Recognized Members to oversee their management. This includes defining scopes and making improvements to titles, descriptions, and the ordering of the items. [You can learn more about the different user roles in a collective here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collectives-user-types).

Members of the collective will be able to add items to a collection, which will require leaving a note adding more context for the addition, which will be visible to everyone who views the collection. Any logged-in Stack Overflow user can also comment on and upvote the collection as a whole. Voting will not affect reputation, and there is no downvote button.

### How can Collections be used?

There are a variety of potential ways to use Collections to benefit a subcommunity on Stack Overflow. Here are two initial use cases:

- **Resource showcase** – creating lists of content that will be resources for the community. Most collectives will be starting off with two collections of this type: an “FAQ” list, and a “Fundamentals” list intended for people just getting started in the collective’s area of practice.
- **Content maintenance** – creating lists of content that needs assessment or action by subject matter experts, such as a list of questions that have outdated answers. The collection could basically function as a to-do list, with recognized Members removing items as more up-to-date answers are added.

The Collections feature allows collective members to work together as a team to build and maintain these lists, and in the case of the content maintenance use case, to work through the actionable items on the lists. Go ahead and add some content to the new collections in the [R Language](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language?tab=collections), [CI/CD](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/ci-cd?tab=collections), [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php?tab=collections), and [NLP](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp?tab=collections) collectives, if any of these are your area of practice!

**What do you think of this feature? Are there other ways it could be useful on the platform?**

**If you have any specific ideas for a collection that would benefit a Collective that you’re a member of, let us know here!**

Comment: Honestly seems a bit weird to see CM's generating collections? but i guess it's better than creating it and not giving an example of how you expected it to be used, like so docs, :shrug:

Comment: Is there value to allowing voting on these at all?

Comment: related-ish: [Allow setting public visibility settings on saves lists, such as "public" and "unlisted"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391888/997587)

Comment: First kind of useful feature for collectives. A bit like awesome lists on Github. Why not open collections for everyone?

Comment: "*Collections enables users...*", => grammatically annoying those terms/names (same with "*Collectives*" + "*Teams*") using a Plural form, but meant to be used as Singular... Grrr...!

Answer (score 56):

Why can we upvote these collections, but not downvote them?

This seems very much contra-intuitive as it looks like a question score but isn't. If these things should have a score, it should reflect how useful the collection is, not how long it's been around and how many people happened to click the upvote button. Without downvotes, the score is largely useless in my opinion.

Comment: This is a good question. After considering a few different options, there were a few reasons why we decided not to include downvotes. Firstly, votes on collections are not connected to rep. We thought following the pattern of comment votes, which also have no downvote and are not connected to rep, rather than making it look the same as Q&A votes, would help to signal that difference to users.

Comment: Secondly, the dynamic nature of Collections makes it difficult to interpret the meaning of a downvote. Someone may downvote a collection because they don’t think there are enough items in it to be useful, for example, but that could change in a matter of minutes if other users add more content. An upvote seems a little more straight forward.

Comment: All of that said, we are very open to feedback on this question. If users feel strongly that downvotes are important to show the value of a collection, we would be interested in hearing more about that.

Comment: @Sasha Your first point is rather invalid. That reputation is tied to voting, should make no difference. The consequences to reputation should never be an issue in terms of voting; voting is not personal, and the effect that it has on a user's reputation, is merely a byproduct. Voting is quality assurance, not a personal interaction.

Comment: In general, comments don't need downvotes as strongly, because they can be addressed with a counter-comment which can then be upvoted. Comments are inbetween a static post (which has up- and downvotes), and messages, which have no votes. You need to provide downvotes unless you have any other satisfactory method of ensuring that kind of feedback. If not, the vote score will simply be a measure of popularity, not quality.

Comment: @Sasha I second on what Andreas said. Reputation is immaterial when interpreting votes. While I agree that downvotes are not that useful for this feature, we need to establish a process for creating collections. Off the top of my head, they should only be created by admins (as-is) and need to be subjected to meta discussions, either for creating new ones or dropping/closing existing ones that are deemed problematic.

Comment: One relevant comparison is Community Wiki posts - they still have the normal voting buttons, even though nobody receives any reputation. That's used to rank them relative to other Questions and Answers, which is presumably the aim of having votes on Collections at all. On the other hand, if the idea is that Collectives are more "community-based" rather than "wisdom of crowds", maybe votes are irrelevant, and they should be arranged manually on a dashboard by any user with a specific permission within the Collective?

Comment: @Sasha Actually, comments should be downvote-able, please.

Comment: @Sasha to be fair, comments should have downvotes too. Ignoring negative sentiment is weird when we rely on the balance to gauge the utility of other contributions. I've certainly seen upvoted comments steer a questioner/answerer/reader down the wrong road and wondered if I was the only one who would have downvoted, given the opportunity. Don't get me wrong, we engage with comments of our own but it's tough to overcome the perception of a _community-endorsed_ comment.

Answer (score 43):

This is just tags, but with extra steps to it.  Why not add this sort of functionality to the base tagging system instead?

Comment: The cynical me would answer that with "because tags were not designed for promoting posts made by recognized members just because they're recognised members".

Comment: @E_net4isonstrike eh, also, this feature doesn't require a member to be recognized to contribute to the ---list--- collection

Comment: @E_net4isonstrike No users, much less recognized members, should be promoting their own posts in collections. I'm concerned that it could happen as well, so I'll at least be on the lookout in the R collective.

Comment: @E_net4isonstrike that's way too cynical. There are issues, concerns, questions, etc. about that feature, but that one is at the bottom of my list, if makes it to the list at all.

Comment: Well... It clearly allows meta-t̵a̵g̵scollections, which certainly must be an improvement, since there's no way we disallow those for a good reason

Comment: In addition to building community around a certain area of practice, Collectives is a space where we can experiment with new ideas in a contained environment, [as stated here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422972/collectives-looking-back). It’s possible that future iterations of Collections could be expanded outside the scope of Collectives. We appreciate feedback on whether or not users would find this beneficial to the platform.

Comment: @Sasha:  I've been struggling a bit with this definition of "community" that seems to be a central anchor of this effort.  In my experience, the usage of the *main* site has been limited to getting an answer from posting a question, and most people don't tend to stick around beyond wanting their question answered.  Do we have numbers on how sticky these communities that Collections are creating actually are?

Comment: To be honest, this whole iteration of Collectives seems to be "tags, but with extra steps to it". Why do I need to "join" the PHP collective, when the existing reputation system already calculates my contribution to the [tag:php] tag? Why do we still have no way of associating tags to each other, other than a synonym system with broken reputation requirements, but Collectives recognise that they are in fact related? What is the difference between content written on the Collective, and content written on a tag wiki?

Answer (score 19):

One of the potential uses I can think of for this feature is to collect high quality duplicate targets. For really common duplicates, it's sometimes hard to find that perfect canonical Q&A that explains things in just the right way using Google.

In theory, we could also annotate the posts in the collection to provide additional context.

Right now, in the R Collective, we're using the FAQ collection since there is very good overlap.

However, one thing that seems to be missing is some way to search a collection once they get too big.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. Making Collections searchable is definitely something that could be considered for future iterations.

Answer (score 16):

It doesn't look broadly useful to me, but, maybe?

Grouping up frequently asked questions for a given language somewhere is great, but, what purpose does it serve if it's somewhere no one who needs such a list looks? Are the lists searchable somehow? Being able to catalog a list like this on tags to be displayed on tag pages and listed below unanswered questions (or even on the ask wizard) with that tag could be a use for this feature outside of collectives.

Using a list to catalog posts that need to be reviewed seems a bit odd, as users who are capable of recognizing that something needs to be reviewed and know that collections exist can probably just review it. The exception here would be if it were used to collect questions that need an action that takes multiple users, such as question closure/reopening or answer/question deletion (SOCVR lite), though, we do have review queues for the former.

---

It's another feature that potentially has a visibility issue due to being behind collectives.

side-note... I'm having a hard time not calling these lists, since that's what they are

Comment: +1 Honestly I am not sure about practicality of the "collections" either. That visibility issue (behind Collectives or not) is a major concern for many features. Take tag-wikis for instance. A lot of useful information and guidance is available, but does anyone see them?

Comment: Seems SO is shopping around for a home or "problem to solve" for a feature no one was really asking for.

Comment: I do like the idea of being able to shove posts that need assistance being closed/reopened into a list, but, the more I think about it the more it already exists and the more I wonder what purpose SOCVR serves, outside of being a more social/enjoyable/collaborative close/reopen queue.

Comment: SOCVR has rules, accountability and discussion. Allowing anyone to shove questions onto a "should be closed and deleted" list is tricky. I guess there can be discussion in the collection comments, but it looks much more poorly designed for that than SO chat (e.g. no built-in to refer to specific posts, starts at oldest instead of newest, etc.).

Comment: @ErikA I absolutely agree with your points, however, there's certainly parallels, and when looking at the differences... if they wanted to turn this feature into something useful, dealing with those differences could do just that.

Comment: Visibility for this feature is definitely a known gap, and the team working on this is considering ways to improve it. Collections are not searchable in this first iteration, but [as I said here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425872/collections-a-new-feature-for-collectives-on-stack-overflow/425881#comment968414_425881) it is something on the table to be considered in the future.

Comment: I would definitely not use them for `cv-pls` but what Ian suggested seems helpful for that purpose.

Comment: eh, I don't see a collection of common dupes as being that useful if it isn't part of the dupe closure UI. At best it becomes a list of questions 2-3 people use that the rest of us don't bother with.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Much more trivial than the concerns raised by others, but the curse of pluralization has struck in the Guidelines sidebar...

> This list was created by **a Collective Admins**. Any Member of the collective can contribute by adding relevant content to the collection.

Comment: One day we'll be able to launch a feature without the curse of pluralization striking... fix coming soon.

Comment: This should be fixed now! Thanks for the heads-up.