# The add post to Collection search box shows incorrect vote and view counts

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, collectives, collections

The process for adding posts to collective [collections](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425872/collections-a-new-feature-for-collectives-on-stack-overflow) includes a search box. When a post appears in the results, information is provided about the post.

However, as can be seen below, the **vote and view** counts incorrectly show zero.
[image: Annotated image that shows incorrect vote and view count]

Interestingly, the answer count is correct.

This is very confusing, when you expect the target to have hundreds of upvotes and millions of views.

<sub>Side note: I was instructed by staff to post bug reports on Meta.SO.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The issue has been fixed.** The issue was only happening when a direct URL was used vs typing in the exact characters from the title.

**Details on what went wrong?**
We weren't correctly passing the full set of data we needed to the frontend to show all numbers because we default those values to 0, when the data is absent, no error is raised.

Comment: Tested and confirmed. Thanks for the speedy fix.