# Should recognized members of Collectives "recommend" answers associated with their own posts?

Tags: discussion, collectives, recognized-members

<sub>This question is inspired by [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426280/should-i-recommend-my-own-answer-as-a-member-of-a-collective?noredirect=1) now deleted (and locked because it was a rejected migration) question.</sub>

Stack Overflow [has a number of Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives) that are [intended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425872/collections-a-new-feature-for-collectives-on-stack-overflow) to "help you find trusted answers faster, connect with subject matter experts from the community, and share knowledge around the technologies you use most."

Glossing over whether they succeed in this mission, Collectives have ["recognized members"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collectives-user-types) that are empowered to shepherd the Collective in various ways. One such power is the ability to ["recommend" answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collectives-recommended-answer) which adds a bit of flair above the answer:

[image: Image of recommended answer flair]

The system prevents you from recommending an answer from a user that was a recognized member at the time they posted the answer. So I couldn't, for example, post an answer to a question tagged with [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) today and then recognize my own answer. However, there is no restriction on historic answers or answers posted to a recognized member's own questions.

I worry that recognized members may have a *conflict of interest* with regards to their own questions and answers. The flair might induce people to give more upvotes on their answers. Also, the possibility of a recommended answer (and associated additional upvotes) could potentially induce someone to be more likely to answer a recognized member's question. On the other hand, we don't limit self-promotion with bounties.

###### Should Collectives' recognized members "recommend" their own historic answers?

###### What about other users' answers posted under their own questions?

<sub>P.S. This is not just a hypothetical question; I have observed this behavior.</sub>

Comment: I mean, given recognized member's answers are implicitly "recommended", I don't see any reason for bias concerns to have any merit... it's built in.

Comment: That's fair, maybe the answer is, "it's totally fine". I just thought it would be good to hear the arguments.

Comment: *"The system prevents you [...]"* - I didn't even notice that the button is missing on my more recent PHP posts until you pointed that out  *"[...] "recommend" their own historic answers?"* - I think this is answer-specific; If the content of the answer is already highly upvoted by other members of the community, I don't see why not (but I also wouldn't really feel the need to at that point, so ‍♂️). *"other users answers [on] their own questions?"* - Agreed it could draw unnecessary attention to the question, but also highlight potentially good answers. So yeah, seems fine, don't abuse 

Comment: It was possible before the official launch of the collectives, beta mode if you will, as a way to test out the feature. But basically most of the reasons that apply to [request for removing the implicit "recommended" badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424338/remove-recognized-by-xyz-collective-text-from-the-recognized-member-rms-fla/424434#424434) are applicable here as well. So, I'd say no, they should no be able to. Besides, we cannot vote on our own posts, I think the same goes here.

Comment: Why not start voting for these recommended answers? If an answer is good enough for it to be recommended by the entire collective, then they can have a feature where one recognized member suggests an answer to be "recommended", the other recognized members review it with whatever form of voting that will decide if it gets to be recommended or not. Ps, I am not much knowledgeable about collectives, so excuse me if I left some detail out.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan Recommended answer is not an answer recommended by whole collective but by one person that is recognized member of the collective. Unfortunately, not all recognized members really deserve that as their answers are far from what is desired from subject matter expert. So there is a plenty of room for abuse.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Well then, the message "Answer recommended by [collectiveName] Collective" is a bit misleading IMHO, It gave the impression that that is considered the suitable answer by the collective, and that's why objected to one "recognized member" marking it as such. Because even if there are recognized members who don't have much expertise, the collective voting mechanism would make up for it probably.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan Yes, it is misleading. There are plenty of issues with collectives as such. One of the issues is that name collective implies some special entity on the site, when in reality it is not so. The main issue with voting is that more people have voting privileges' that those that have downvoting, Also downvoting answers cots some reputation, so only higher reputation users will downvote often. So there is not enough high reputation users and curators to balance things out and they are usually more focused to moderating really poor, rather than meh posts.

Comment: The simplest option would be to update the text from *"recommended by X collective"* to "recommended by <user1234> as part of X collective." That would give viewers the necessary info to make their own judgement, and could potentially dissuade recognised users from abusing the feature.

Comment: "Should Collectives' recognized members "recommend" their own historic answers?" Only if they think that these answers deserve recommendation (whatever that is).